# How to get all double values from a method which returns a double array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, methods, double

I have two methods (which are in `Points.java`) which return a `double array`. Now I want to get all values from both methods.

Methods:

- getX()
- getY()

I thought:

```
    public void addNewPoints(Point p){
    for (int i = 0; i < p.getX().length; i++)

        dataset.add(p.getX(i),p.getY(i));
}
```

`In Point.java:`

```
    public static double[] getX() {

    return new double[] {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0};
}

public static double[] getY() {

    return new double[] {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0};
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getX() and getY() methods return arrays. Arrays use the index operator, which is just a pair of square brackets:

```
dataset.add(p.getX()[i],p.getY()[i]);
```

This might look goofy, but it's the same as doing this:

```
double[] xArray = getX();
double[] yArray = getY();

for (int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){
   dataset.add(xArray[i],yArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: But now getX() and getY() aren't methods anymore

Comment: That's incorrect, actually - you need `dataset.add(p.getX()[i],p.getY()[i]);`